# How can I set Ember embedded association keys to match expected nested_attributes_for format on the Rails side?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ember-data, nested-attributes

I've got an Ember model with a nested association. When I POST to the Rails server, Ember is sending:

```
  Parameters: {"parent"=>{"name"=>"Jim", "kid"=>{"name"=>'Sara'}}
```

On the Rails side, the parent accepts_nested_attributes_for kid, which means that the Rails model is expecting:

```
  Parameters: {"parent"=>{"name"=>"Jim", "kid_attributes"=>{"name"=>'Sara'}}
```

I'm currently handling this by editing the params hash in the Rails controller before I call create on the parent model. That's a hack, clearly. I'm sure there's some way to reconfigure the expected key for embedded associations. (I'm thinking it'd be preferable to do this on the  client-side, but I don't have strong feelings about it.)

Any advice for how to handle this? Either on the Rails side or the Ember side is fine. Thanks.